# Median filter nullifies the numpy array value

Tags: numpy, image-processing, scipy, python-imaging-library, conv-neural-network

I have an image which I converted to numpy array and after that applying median filter using scipy library on that changes all elements of that ndarray to zero.I don't know why this is happening and I assume it should not happen.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import medfilt

train = np.array(Image.open("26.jpg").getdata()  ,dtype=float).reshape(176, 208, 1)


s = np.sum(train, axis =0)
print(s)

train = medfilt(train, kernel_size= 3) 
s1 = np.sum(train, axis =0)
print(s1)
```

**Due to this issue I can't go for further image processing.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`medfilt` effectively zeropads at the boundaries. Since you have one dimension of size 1, in this direction every pixel is sandwiched between two zeros which outvote everything.

Try omitting the third dimension

```
train = np.array(Image.open("26.jpg").getdata()  ,dtype=float).reshape(176, 208)
```

and you should be fine.

You can add it after filtering if need be.